# Routing to properties in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, get, razor-pages

Let's say I add a property in my page model in Razor Pages for some sort of id number:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Then I can set the `Id` via the URL like this:

> localhost:5001/?Id=1

However, often (e.g. when creating API's) you get a much prettier (at least I think so) way to set the `Id`, by doing this:

> localhost:5001/Id/1

By default this doesn't seem to work with Razor Pages. Is there any way to enable it?

*Note: I have tried to Google this, but I am bit unsure about the terminology. Is it also called routing when setting properties?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Route Data](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-data). You can specify placeholders for route data parameters in a route template as part of the `@page` directive:

```
@page "{id}" // will match localhost:5001/1
```

If you want the term "Id" to appear in the URL (e.g to match `localhost:5001/Id/1`), your route template will look like this:

```
@page "Id/{id}"
```

Normally, you don't include the name of the parameter in the route template.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Is it possuble to handle null values (no input via URL) this way? If I do not add anything, it will give me a 404 Page not found.

Comment: After some Googling, I found out myself. If you write `{id?}` it will send null if no input is provided in the URL. Maybe you can add that to your answer, if other people has the same issue :-).

Comment: The page I linked to explains how to work with optional parameters.

Comment: It most certainly does. My bad :-). And thank you once again for the assitance. I am really starting to fall in love with the simplicity of Razor Pages.